# How can I dynamically switch between two displays connected through a mipi mux and bridge on my embedded platform?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have an embedded platform with a single mipi output connected to a mipi mux that is in turn connected to a mipi display and a mipi to display port bridge. Ultimately I would like to dynamically switch between the two displays but I’m questioning how feasible this is. I started modeling the display port bridge in the device tree only to realize the dsi and DP endpoints are bound to each other making that a seemingly static approach. My only other thought is to write a kernel module that can load and configure two separate display drivers with some sysfs type interface that can be used to switch between the two.

I’m looking for suggestions on how to approach this problem before I attempt a specific implementation.